# php Javascript variable quoting error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm having trouble with quotes in a line of the attached code.

It is part of a picture viewer. Picture data url "PicNotes" is read from mysql. I am attempting to enhance the result by adding a picture info pop-up but can't get the quotes right.

I have added some rem statements around 3 versions (attempts) to get it working.

```
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE type='$type' LIMIT $start, $limit_col_1");}
// Your while loop here
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data))
{//REM If there is no info don't show the info link
    if ($row[PicNotes]) {
//  $icon=<a href="JavaScript:Popup('notes/$row['PicNotes']');"> <img src='images/info.png'></a>; //REM This line was the original call for the pop-up script
//  $icon = "<a href=notes/tempest_series.php><img src=images/info.png></a>"; //REM This line works but does not have any of the Jarvascript or URL variable from the DB
//  $icon = "<a href=notes/$row[PicNotes]><img src=images/info.png></a>"; //REM This  line doesn't crash but the URL is corrupted
    $icon = "<a href="JavaScript:Popup(notes/$row[PicNotes]);"><img src=images/info.png></a>"; //REM This line crashes with an "Unexpected T_STRING error 
    }else{
    $icon='';}
// Display LHS Thumbnail and Viewer Pic Data

    echo "<a href='images/".$row['vfile']."' rel='enlargeimage::mouseover' rev='loadarea' title='&lt;b&gt;".$row['Title']."&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;".$row['Medium']." &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; ".$row['iw']." x ".$row['ih']." cm. $icon'><img border='1' src='images/".$row['tnfile']."
    ' alt='' width='".$row['tnx']."' height='".$row['tny']."' class='tn' /></a><br />";

}
```

Please can somebody put me on the right track.

Comment: When you begin "<a href=" you closed on that ". Try this sort of format. $var = "<a href='javascript:'>link</a>";

Answer (score 1):

1) Escape the inner quotes:

```
$icon = "<a href=\"JavaScript:Popup(notes/$row[PicNotes])\"><img src=images/info.png></a>";
```

2) Use single quotes:

```
$icon = "<a href='JavaScript:Popup(notes/$row[PicNotes])'><img src=images/info.png></a>";
```

Comment: Escaping the inner quotes does stop the crashing, however the resulting link is corrupted, it has a ";" appended. Deleting the ";" in the code produces a "correct" link but this results in an error - Error on Page - notes is undefined. Using single quotes caused major corruption to the resulting display

Comment: Just delete the semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks @John Conde but I had already covered that in mu previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces ({}) for better variable concatenation

```
$icon="<a href=\"JavaScript:Popup('notes/{$row[PicNotes]}');\"><img src=\"images/info.png\"></a>";
```

Comment: Thanks @kangaswad but that doesn't help. I still get a browser error "'notes' is undefined" If I leave the semicolon in then the it gets added to the URL, I also have to remove the single quotes or the picture viewer is corrupted.